# Balanced sets and zero

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces

A set is said to be *balanced* if for all $t$ in $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ such that $|t|<1$, we have $tA\subset A$.

Let $B$ be a balanced set in any topological vector space. Then $0$ belongs to $B$??

Comment: What does $tA$ look like when $t=0$?

Comment: If A is symmetric then 0 belongs to A too?

Comment: @postmortes has answered you !

Answer (score 0):

This is almost too trivial, but $t=0$ obeys $|t| < 1$ and $tA = \{0\}$ for $t=0$ so $\{0\} \subseteq A$ and thus $0 \in A$ is immediate.